# NGINX кэширование блокирует перенаправление

Tags: nginx

Собственно следующая ситуация:
Имеется директива

```
    location /content/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /image.php;
    }
```

Смысл следующий, в данной папке и во вложенных папках находится контент - в основном изображения и их миниатюры, следовательно если миниатюра отсутствует то обращение к скрипту image.php её создаёт. В таком варианте всё работает хорошо.
Но если добавить кэширование ресурсов:

```
    location /content/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /image.php;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf|woff|woff2)$ {
            allow all;
            expires 365d;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

    }
```

перенаправление перестаёт работать.
Кто в курсе, что поправить, чтобы и кэширование работало и скрипт отрабатывал при отсутствии миниатюр?

Comment: Убрать вложенный location. Изучить как именно ваш запрос обрабатывается nginx-ом и не копипастить бездумно конфиги ищ интернета

Comment: Решение нашёл. Кстати, не копипастил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем вот решение, если кто столкнется, можно вот так:

```
location /content/ {
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf|woff|woff2)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /image.php;
            allow all;
            expires 365d;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

    }
```